# Algorithm for smarter window placement

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am developing ExtJS application with multiple movable ExtJS windows on page. By default ExtJS creates all new windows to the same predefined positions, which will put new windows to the same spot. As the application can open 10+ windows for user, this is quite bad for usability. At this moment I notice constantly having several windows at the center of my screen on top of each other (default behavior).

**Is anyone aware of a simple algorithm that I could use to determine smarter placement for new windows?**

I would prefer something that is not very complex, but would still improve the usability of my application. Most of the windows are by default relatively small so there should be emptier space available on the screen. I know I can query the WindowMgr for information about present windows, but I still need some kind of logic to follow.

I guess could just add 10 pixels to default x and y to cascade the windows, but that feels a bit dumb.

Comment: That's what Windows does though... :-)

Comment: Cascading is what windows users are used to and most people are on windows so why not stick with a familiar UI.  Otherwise I suggest you go with a widget approach and use drap and drop zones for placement.

Comment: At the time that you start opening the windows, do you know the total number of windows that will be opened?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer No, it depends on what the user does in the application. That makes the situation a bit harder I guess (otherwise I would tile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cascade all the current windows with something like the following. Change it to your liking

```
Ext.Array.each(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('window'), function(win, index){
   win.setPosition(index * 10, index * 10);        
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q93Zt/1/